# Apache folder redirect to a subfolder, without invalidating direct access to the subfolders

Tags: regex, apache

I have this directories structure:

```
www
-- subfolder
---- .htaccess
---- folder1
-------- file1.jpg
---- folder2
-------- file2.jpg
---- folder3
-------- file3.jpg
```

What should I type in the "**.htaccess**" file, so that all file requests in the "`subfolder/`" are redirected to the "`subfolder/folder3`" path without however preventing correct and direct access to the files in the "`subfolder/folder1`", "`subfolder/folder2`" and "`subfolder/folder3`"? (as if there were symbolic links in the subfolder to files in folder3)

Expected result:

```
www.example.com/subfolder/folder1/file1.jpg --> www.example.com/subfolder/folder1/file1.jpg
www.example.com/subfolder/folder2/file2.jpg --> www.example.com/subfolder/folder2/file2.jpg
www.example.com/subfolder/folder3/file3.jpg --> www.example.com/subfolder/folder3/file3.jpg
www.example.com/subfolder/file3.jpg --> www.example.com/subfolder/folder3/file3.jpg
```

Solutions "`RewriteRule ^(^\/+)$ /folder3/$1 [L]`" and "`RedirectMatch ^(^\/+)$ /folder3/$1`" don't work

**Edit (solution):**

I finally solved the problem with commands:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder3/$1 [L]
```

although I still don't understand why the previous solutions didn't work.